# unable to show states and health check on gravitee io?

Tags: gravitee

I have setup new gravitee APIM in which i have add few api which targets fast and flask api in the backend. i want check the statistics and health of it but when go check on the default dashboard it doesn't show any status just a counter that apis has been added.